# Array.map() doesn't render anything in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to make a list in my react app. I have retrieved data from my database, and pushed it into a list. I have doublechecked that the data shows up correctly in the console, and it does, but array.map() returns nothing. I think the problem might be that array.map() runs two times. I don't know why it runs two times.

```
function Dashboard() {
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    const [teams, setTeams] = useState([])
    const history = useHistory();

    useEffect(() => {
        getTeams()

        if (user) {

        } else {
            history.push("/")
        }
    }, [])

    function Welcome() {
        if (user) {
            return <h1>Welcome, {user.displayName}</h1>
        } else {

        }
    }

    const getTeams = () => {
        firebase.firestore().collectionGroup('members').where('user', '==', user.uid).get().then((snapshot) => {
            const docList = []
            snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    docList.push({
                        teamId: doc.data().teamId,
                    })
            })
            const teamslist = []
            docList.forEach((data) => {
                firebase.firestore().collection('teams').doc(data.teamId).get().then((doc) => {
                    teamslist.push({
                        name: doc.data().name,
                        teamId: doc.id,
                    })
                })
            })
            setTeams(teamslist)
        })
    }

    const openTeam = (data) => {
        console.log(data.teamId)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Welcome />
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {console.log(teams)}
                    {teams.map((data) => {
                        return (
                            <li onClick={() => openTeam(data)} key={data.teamId}>
                                <h1>{data.name}</h1>
                                <p>{data.teamId}</p>
                            </li>
                        )
                        })}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Dashboard
```

[image: teams array]

Comment: Where do you use getTeams, i'm assuming you have an effect or something related to get data, upload full code to see what you're missing

Comment: What does your `teams` array look like?

Comment: Full code uploaded. ```teams array``` has two objects. Both have a teamid and a name called ```teamId``` and ```name```

Comment: I can't stamp out a full answer right now, but this is caused by calling `setTeams` with an empty array because you aren't waiting for it to be filled first.

Comment: @samthecodingman when I console.log ```teams``` right above the array.map, I get the console output in the image above.

Comment: @DanielOlsen When you log an object in a modern browser, the reference to that object is logged, not it's value when it was logged. Change `console.log(teams)` to `console.log([...teams])` or `console.log(JSON.stringify(teams))` to see it's actual dereferenced value.

Comment: I get two console outputs. One array with the same data as the image above, and one empty array. Seems like the console.log runs two times. Maybe the .map() does that too. I don't know why it's happening though.

Comment: Did you replace the log statements as above? Also you will get two logs because your initial state for teams is `[]` and the second log is after your `getTeams()` function called `setTeams` which triggered a rerender

Comment: I changed the log statements as you described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getTeams` function has a bug where it isn't waiting for the `firebase.firestore().collection('teams').doc(data.teamId).get().then` promises to finish before calling `setTeams`, so it is called with an empty array, causing React to trigger a render with the empty array.

As the promises for fetching each team resolve they will be pushed to the same array reference, but this won't trigger a rerender in React since you're not calling `setTeams` again when the array changes.

Try this code, which won't call `setTeams` until each team promise generated from `docList` has been resolved.

```js
const getTeams = () => {
    firebase.firestore().collectionGroup('members').where('user', '==', user.uid).get().then((snapshot) => {
        const docList = []

        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            docList.push({
                teamId: doc.data().teamId,
            })
        })

        const teamslist = [];

        Promise.all(docList.map((data) => {
            return firebase
                .firestore()
                .collection('teams')
                .doc(data.teamId)
                .get()
                .then((doc) => {
                    teamslist.push({
                        name: doc.data().name,
                        teamId: doc.id,
                    })
                })
        }))
            .then(() => setTeams(teamslist));
    })
}
```

A smaller edit would be to call `setTeams` after each separate team promise resolves, which will trigger a React render each time a new team is resolved:

```js
.then((doc) => {
    teamslist.push({
        name: doc.data().name,
        teamId: doc.id,
    });
    // create a new array, since using the same array
    // reference won't cause react to rerender
    setTeams([...teamslist]);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to [@martinstark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5474782/martinstark) who provided you [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67390226/3068190) while I was unavailable.

However, there are some more things that need to be covered.

#### User State

In your current component, you pull the current user from Firebase Authentication, but don't handle the state changes of that user - signing in, signing out, switching user. If a user is signed in and they were to navigate directly to your dashboard, [`firebase.auth().currentUser`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) could be momentarily `null` while it resolves the user's login state, which would incorrectly send them off to your login page.

This can be added using:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(() => firebase.auth().currentUser || undefined);
const userLoading = user === undefined;

useEffect(() => firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(setUser), []);
```

Next, in your first `useEffect` call, you call `getTeams()` whether the user is signed in or not - but it should depend on the current user.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (userLoading) {
    return; // do nothing (yet)
  } else if (user === null) {
    history.push("/");
    return;
  }
  
  getTeams()
    .catch(setError);
}, [user]);
```

```
// This getTeams() is a () => Promise<void>
const getTeams = async () => {
  const membersQuerySnapshot = await firebase.firestore()
    .collectionGroup('members')
    .where('user', '==', user.uid)
    .get();
  
  const docList = []
  membersQuerySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    docList.push({
      teamId: doc.get("teamId"), // better perfomance than `doc.data().teamId`
    });
  });

  const teamDataList = [];

  await Promise.all(docList.map((data) => {
    return firebase.firestore()
      .collection('teams')
      .doc(data.teamId)
      .get()
      .then(doc => teamDataList.push({
        name: doc.get("name"),
        teamId: doc.id
      }));
  }));

  setTeams(teamDataList);
}
```

#### Optimizing `getTeams()` - Network Calls

The `getTeams` function in your question calls `setTeams` with the array `[]`, which will be empty at the time of calling it as covered in [@martinstark's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5474782/martinstark) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67390226/3068190). The "get team data" operations are asyncronous and you aren't waiting for them to resolve before updating your state and triggering a new render. While you are pushing data to them after the component has rendered, modifying the array won't trigger a new render.

While you could fetch the data for each team using `db.collection("teams").doc(teamId).get()`, each of these is requests is a network call, and you can only make a limited number of these in parallel. So instead of fetching 1 team per network call, you could fetch up to 10 teams per network call instead using the [`in` operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any) and [`FieldPath.documentId()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldPath#documentid).

Assuming the `collectionGroup("members")` targets the collections of documents at `/teams/{aTeamId}/members` which contain (at least):

```
"/teams/{aTeamId}/members/{memberUserId}": {
  teamId: aTeamId,
  user: memberUserId, // if storing an ID here, call it "uid" or "userId" instead
  /* ... */
}
```

```
// this utility function lives outside of your component near the top/bottom of the file
function chunkArr(arr, n) {
  if (n <= 0) throw new Error("n must be greater than 0");
  return Array
    .from({length: Math.ceil(arr.length/n)})
    .map((_, i) => arr.slice(n*i, n*(i+1)))
}

// This getTeams() is a () => Promise<void>
const getTeams = async () => {
  const membersQuerySnapshot = await firebase.firestore()
    .collectionGroup('members')
    .where('user', '==', user.uid)
    .get();

  const teamIDList = []
  membersQuerySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    teamIDList.push(doc.get("teamId")); // better perfomance than `doc.data().teamId`
  })

  const chunkedTeamIDList = chunkArr(teamIDList, 10) // split into batches of 10
  const teamsColRef = firebase.firestore().collection('teams');
  const documentId = firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(); // used with where() to target the document's ID
  const foundTeamDocList = await Promise
    .all(chunkedTeamIDList.map((chunkOfTeamIDs) => {
      // fetch each batch of IDs
      return teamsColRef
        .where(documentId, 'in', chunkOfTeamIDs)
        .get();
    }))
    .then((arrayOfQuerySnapshots) => {
      // flatten results into a single array
      const allDocsList = [];
      arrayOfQuerySnapshots.forEach(qs => allDocsList.push(...qs.docs));
      return allDocsList;
    });

  const teamDataList = foundTeamDocList
    .map((doc) => ({ name: doc.get("name"), teamId: doc.id }));

  // sort by name, then by ID
  teamDataList.sort((aTeam, bTeam) =>
    aTeam.name.localeCompare(bTeam.name) || aTeam.teamId.localeCompare(bTeam.teamId)
  )

  // update state & trigger render
  setTeams(teamDataList);
}
```

You can also make use of [this utility function](https://gist.github.com/samthecodingman/aea3bc9481bbab0a7fbc72069940e527) to simplify & optimize the code a bit. Which gives:

```
// This getTeams() is a () => Promise<void>
const getTeams = async () => {
  const membersQuerySnapshot = await firebase.firestore()
    .collectionGroup('members')
    .where('user', '==', user.uid)
    .get();

  const teamIDList = []
  membersQuerySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    teamIDList.push(doc.get("teamId")); // better perfomance than `doc.data().teamId`
  })
  
  const teamsColRef = firebase.firestore().collection('teams');
  const teamDataList = [];
  await fetchDocumentsWithId(
    teamsColRef,
    teamIDList,
    (doc) => teamDataList.push({ name: doc.get("name"), teamId: doc.id })
  );

  // sort by name, then by ID
  teamDataList.sort((aTeam, bTeam) =>
    aTeam.name.localeCompare(bTeam.name) || aTeam.teamId.localeCompare(bTeam.teamId)
  )

  // update state & trigger render
  setTeams(teamDataList);
}
```

#### Optimizing `getTeams()` - Function Definition

As part of the last optimization, you could pull it out of your component or place it in its own file so that it's not redefined with every render:

```
// define at top/bottom of the file outside your component
// This getTeams() is a (userId: string) => Promise<{ name: string, teamId: string}[]>
async function getTeams(userId) => {
  const membersQuerySnapshot = await firebase.firestore()
    .collectionGroup('members')
    .where('user', '==', userId)
    .get();

  const teamIDList = []
  membersQuerySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    teamIDList.push(doc.get("teamId")); // better perfomance than `doc.data().teamId`
  })

  const teamsColRef = firebase.firestore().collection('teams');
  const teamDataList = [];
  await fetchDocumentsWithId(
    teamsColRef,
    teamIDList,
    (doc) => teamDataList.push({ name: doc.get("name"), teamId: doc.id })
  );

  // sort by name, then by ID
  teamDataList.sort((aTeam, bTeam) =>
    aTeam.name.localeCompare(bTeam.name) || aTeam.teamId.localeCompare(bTeam.teamId)
  )

  // return the sorted teams
  return teamDataList
}
```

and update how you use it:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (userLoading) {
    return; // do nothing
  } else if (user === null) {
    history.push("/");
    return;
  }
  
  getTeams(user.uid)
    .then(setTeams)
    .catch(setError);
}, [user]);
```